# Getting a particular date using current date as reference

Tags: c#, datetime, date, timespan

I want to get two particular dates by using current date, let me explain more.

For example if today is 10/27/2011 then I would like to have 7/01/2011 and 9/30/2011. Note that its a three month period (excluding current month) How can I do that ?

Currently I am following a self designed method but I think its far from good. Here is the code.

```
    TimeSpan TSFrom = new TimeSpan(90 + DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan TSTo = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now.Subtract(TSFrom).ToShortDateString());
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now.Subtract(TSTo).ToShortDateString());
```

This code return these values

7/2/2011 - 9/30/2011

while its some what acceptable its still looks like not a perfect way to go and look the first date is starting from the second day of month while it should start from first day, I think its because some months end on 29 while some on 30. So how can I get the perfect dates like 7/1/2011 to 9/30/2011.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var end = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1).AddDays(-1); // Last day of previous month
var start = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-3); // First day of third-last month
```

(You could store `new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1)` in a local variable, this is a matter of personal taste, I guess ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
DateTime firstOfMonth = now.AddDays(-now.Day + 1);
DateTime beginning = firstOfMonth.AddMonths(-3);
DateTime end = firstOfMonth.AddDays(-1);
```

We "roll back" to the beginning of the month by subtracting the (current day - 1),
the end of the period is `firstOfMonth.AddDays(-1);`, the beginning of the period is `firstOfMonth.AddMonths(-3);`

Comment: -1: This is obviously incorrect: if you insert the values given in the question (i.e. current date is 2011/10/27) you'll get 2011/10/1-2011/12/31 instead of 2011/7/1-2011/9/30 ... Also I think, Ahmed didn't want to get fixed "quarterly" periods, but only the three preceding months.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fromWithDay = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);
var from = new DateTime(fromWithDay.Year, fromWithDay.Month, 1);
var toWithDay = DateTime.Today;
var to = new DateTime(toWithDay.Year, toWithDay.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
```

It could be even shorter but less readable

Comment: Good, except it is `var toWithDay = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @Otiel, I think the OP is only interested in dates, not times, or am I missing something?

Comment: No you're right, but my comment wasn't about dates or times. In your snippet, `to` would be equal to `31/01/2012`, whereas the OP would like `30/09/2011`. Use `var toWithDay = DateTime.Now;` or `var toWithDay = DateTime.Today;` instead of `var toWithDay = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(4);` and then it will respect OP's request.

Comment: @Otiel, ahhh got it, thanks, (I'm slow in the morning)... will fix the answer accordingly

Comment: Wrong again ;). It's not `var toWithDay = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
` but `var toWithDay = DateTime.Today;`.

Comment: @Otiel, you're right, he doesn't want the last day of the current month but the last day of the previous month. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime firstDayOfThisMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
DateTime startDate = firstDayOfThisMonth.AddMonths(-3);
DateTime endDate = firstDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(-1);
Console.WriteLine(startDate);
Console.WriteLine(endDate);
```